# Select tag onchange not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting an onchange event on select tags like this:

```
Dictionary.prototype.setSelectEvent = function setSelectEvent() {
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.dictionary-page__select');

    if (selects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
            selects[i].onchange = function() {
                this.onChange();
            }.bind(this);
        }
    }
};
```

This works fine on the desktop. The event is properly set and fired with no errors. On mobile, the event is not being fired at all. I tried with onblur as well, but that did nothing. Using vanilla javascript, how can I set an event on a select tag and have it work on mobile?

Solution:
Third party library was overriding desktop events, but not mobile ones. Had to pass the select object in the event.

```
Dictionary.prototype.setSelectEvent = function setSelectEvent() {
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.dictionary-page__select');

    var that = this;

    if (selects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
            selects[i].onchange = function() {
                that.onChange(this);
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you add your html please?

Comment: Shouldn't `for (var i = 0; i < selects; i++) {`   be  `for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {` (or even better, taking in account performance `        for (var i = 0, len = selects.length; i < len; i++) {`  )

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo. Fixed. Found the problem. I was using a third party javascript library to style the select tag. It overrode my events on desktop, but not mobile which led to a huge amount of issues. Anyway, issue is solved. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Libraries are great, until they aren't ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary.prototype.setSelectEvent = function setSelectEvent() {
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.dictionary-page__select');

    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].onchange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
};
```

The preceding code should do what you're looking for, integrates over the NodeList it until `selects.length`.  Also you'll note you can directly bind to `this`, we don't need to define a new onChange function each time that calls an `onChange` method on the `Dictionary`.

Edit: removed the conversion to an array.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the `NodeList` to an array? `NodeList` is array-like, so you can use `selectList.length` and `selectList[i]`.

Comment: In this case you're right, we're not doing anything that can't be done with the NodeList directly, fixed.  Great point!